# Where do I want to code filters to get a more granular piece of redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a somewhat comprehensive object that exists within my redux-store and I want to condense it down to just an array of specific keys. Do I want to code this filter logic in `mapStateToProps` ?

Typically, I have something that takes form like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    budgetCategories: state.getIn(['budget', 'budgetCategories']).toJS(),
    budgetFormEditable: state.getIn(['budget', 'budgetFormEditable']).toJS(),
    reduxForm: state.getIn(['form']).toJS()
  }
}
```

Wondering if I want to strip out single item using a filter and map, if it would be reasonable to put this is the same function.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need selectors.
Redux documentation suggests to put them alongside the reducer because if the state form changes, selectors will need to be changed as well.
https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/CodeStructure.html#structure-file-structure